# footer on very bottom of page HTML

Tags: html, css

I know a lot of people asked that already but nothing seems to work. I want my footer to be on the bottom of the page. So far it is on the bottom of the screen, but if the page is bigger and you need to scroll, it just sticks there and stays in the middle. If I put `position: fixed` the footer scrolls with you. I want it to be at the **VERY BOTTOM** of the page, though, so you have to scroll down to see it in the first place, if the page is too big.

I tried several different wrappers and pushers but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You need `position: absolute;` then.

Comment: @connexo on what? my footer is already on position: absolute;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

Comment: @MateuszJuruś tried as described in there, same issue still

Comment: @alex what is the problem with `position: fixed`

Comment: You have `html {height:100%}` which is 100% of the window, and the footer is positioned at its bottom. The rest is what overflows out of the html.

Comment: Replace `height` by `min-height`.

Comment: @Bhuwan if I do `position: fixed` the footer scrolls with the page. I want it to be at the bottom of the whole page so you don't see it until you scroll to it

Comment: @alex then you dont need to use any position values to footer...its a `float` issue...you are using `float` in a wrong way..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, hope this will help you

Remove `min-height` for pageimg class and content class then you will get your output.

```css
.pagelist {
  background-color: deeppink;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  height: 70%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.pageimg {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  /* min-height: 500px; */
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.pageimg img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.pagetext {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.pageframe {
  position: absolute;
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.comiclist {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 90%;
}

.floatbutt-right {
  float: right;
}

.floatbutt-left {
  float: left
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: grey;
}

.footer span {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.spacer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 95px;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -30px;
  /* Footer */
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
<img class="logo" src="inc/logo.png" />
komix.lit
<button id="home" class="navbutt" onClick="location.href='home.php'">Home</button>
<button id="comics" class="navbutt" onClick="location.href='komix.php'">Komix</button>
<button id="login" class="navbutt" onClick="location.href='login.php'">Einloggen</button></div>
<div class="content">
<div class="spacer"></div><div class="pagelist"><ul style="list-style-type: none;"><li><a style='text-decoration: none; color: black;' href='pages.php?id=84'>Seite 1</a></li><li><a style='text-decoration: none; color: black;' href='pages.php?id=86'>Seite 2</a></li><li><a style='text-decoration: none; color: black;' href='pages.php?id=85'>Seite 3</a></li></ul></div><div class='pageframe'><div class='pageimg' style='height: 1024;'>
                        <img src='komix\19_03_18_10_21_31-12.jpg'
                        alt='seite 1' style='max-width:100%'/> </div><div class='pagetext'>seite 1</div><button class='floatbutt-right' onClick="location.href='pages.php?id=86'">nächste Seite</button></div></div>
<div class="footer">
        <span>text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried to apply your changes, but the issue remains the same

Comment: but i implemented this code, its working on my end. Did you use the same code?

Comment: i didnt edit my code since i posted it here and commented out the parts you told me to... weird

Answer (score 0):

You should overthink your layout and read about the HTML box model.

I put all your elements in a wrapper which is *position: relative*, so the footer with *position: absolute* can align properly. Also I had to remove *position: absolute* of *.pageframe*:

```css
.pagelist {
  background-color: deeppink;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  height: 70%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.pageimg {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.pageimg img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.pagetext {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.pageframe {
  /* position: absolute; */ 
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.comiclist {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 90%;
}

.floatbutt-right {
  float: right;
}

.floatbutt-left {
  float: left
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: grey;
}

.footer span {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.spacer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 95px;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -30px;
  /* Footer */
}

#wrapper {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<head lang="de">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/layout.css">
  <script src="inc/javascript.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>komix.lit</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="navbar">
    <img class="logo" src="inc/logo.png" /> komix.lit
    <button id="home" class="navbutt" onClick="location.href='home.php'">Home</button>
    <button id="comics" class="navbutt" onClick="location.href='komix.php'">Komix</button>
    <button id="login" class="navbutt" onClick="location.href='login.php'">Einloggen</button></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="pagelist">
      <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
        <li><a style='text-decoration: none; color: black;' href='pages.php?id=84'>Seite 1</a></li>
        <li><a style='text-decoration: none; color: black;' href='pages.php?id=86'>Seite 2</a></li>
        <li><a style='text-decoration: none; color: black;' href='pages.php?id=85'>Seite 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='pageframe'>
      <div class='pageimg' style='height: 1024;'>
        <img src='komix\19_03_18_10_21_31-12.jpg' alt='seite 1' style='max-width:100%' /> </div>
      <div class='pagetext'>seite 1</div><button class='floatbutt-right' onClick="location.href='pages.php?id=86'">nächste Seite</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <span>text</span>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```